# Does setting an array (int*) to NULL free the memory it occupies?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, null

Say I have an array declared as:

```
int* array;
```

and I fill the array with however many integers.

If I later say

```
array = NULL;
```

does this free the memory that the numbers in array occupied, or does it just make the array unusable while the memory still lingers?

Comment: It will be a memory leak if you used `new`.

Comment: In short: No! Use delete, if the memory was heap allocated (using `new`).

Comment: `int* array;` is not an array in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allocated the memory using `new []` (more likely, since the name of the variable is `array`) or `new`, this will result in a **memory leak**.

Setting the pointer to `NULL` will not release the memory, only reassign the pointer. In other words, you will lose any chance to refer to the previously allocated memory.

Use `delete[]` to release memory allocated with `new[]`, and `delete` to release memory allocated with `new`.

However, consider *not* using raw pointers and manual memory management at all, they are most often not needed and error-prone. The C++ Standard Library comes with collections and smart pointers that perform memory management under the hood and keep you safe from this kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

`int* array;` is not an array, it's a pointer. You have no array at this point. You can't start doing `array[0] = 5;` or anything because it doesn't even point at a valid `int` object, let alone an array of `int`s.

An array is declared by doing:

```
int array[5];
```

This array *does* have 5 objects ready for you to start assigning to. However, this array *must not* be `delete`d. The array was not dynamically allocated.

However, if you were to have done `int* array = new int[5];`, you would by dynamically allocating an array of 5 `int`s and getting a pointer to the first element in that array. In this case, you *must* `delete[] array;`. If you don't and only set the pointer to `NULL` or `nullptr`, you will only leak memory.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the code

```
int *array;
array = NULL;
```

you have initialized the pointer. When you assign data to *array

```
int *array;
array[1] = 3;
```

you get an undefined behavior, but in most cases an access violation.  When you allocate memory before writing and assign NULL to the pointer

```
int *array;
array = new int[3];
array[0] = 2;
array[2] = 4;
array = NULL;
```

you get a memory leak. Everything should be fine, when you delete the data:

```
int *array;
array = new int[3];
array[0] = 2;
array[2] = 4;
delete[] array;
array = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the array to NULL does **not** free the memory.

Weather it is usable will depend on the surrounding code and how `array` is initialized. But you have not provided that information so anything else would be speculation.

Note it is unusual to use pointers in modern C++ code.
You should be looking to use a more appropriate structure. What that is will depend on what your usage us. Based on the name alone `array`. You should probably be using `std::vector<int>` (or `std::array<int>` C++11) or even a plain old C array `int array[5]`.

Answer (score 0):

it will leak the memory and it will only be freed when the process exits.
There is every chance that a segmenation fault may occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
int *array = new int[10];
```

you need to use

```
delete [] array;
```

to free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically follow the rule: Whenever allocating with `new XXX` deallocate with `delete XXX`or for array allocation `delete [] XXX`.

If you just use `array = NULL`, you only set the pointer to `NULL` and you will have a memory leak.